# How to use PostgreSQL's stored procedures or functions in Django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am working on one Django project. And I decided to write logic code in PostgreSQL instead of writing in Python. So, I created a stored procedure in PostgreSQL. For example, a stored procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace procedure close_credit(id_loan int)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    update public.loan_loan
    set sum = 0
    where id = id_loan;
    commit;
end;$$
```

Then in settings.py, I made the following changes:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'pawnshop',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': password.database_password,
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

So the question is, How can I call this stored procedure in views.py?

p.s.

Maybe it sounds like a dumb question, but I really couldn't find any solution in Django.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend storing the procedure definition in a migration file.  For example, in the directory **`myapp/migrations/sql.py`**:

```
from django.db import migrations

SQL = """
create procedure close_credit(id_loan int)
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    update public.loan_loan
    set sum = 0
    where id = id_loan;
    commit;
end;$$
"""

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    
    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [migrations.RunSQL(SQL)]
```

**Note**: you will need to replace **`myapp`** with the name of your application, and you will need to include **only** the ***most recent*** migration file for your app as a dependency.

Now you can install the procedure using **`python3 manage.py migrate`**.

Once your procedure is defined in the database, you can call it using **[`cursor.callproc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#calling-stored-procedures)**:

```
from django.db import connection

def close_credit(id_loan):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.callproc('close_credit', [id_loan])
```

All that being said, if your procedure is really as trivial as the example you provided, it would cost much less in maintenance to write the equivalent using the **ORM**:

```
Loan.objects.filter(id=id_loan).update(sum=0)
```