# Error when calling Procedure from Django: No procedure matches the given name and argument types

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stored-procedures, django-migrations

I want to call a stored procedure installed in our PostgreSQL database
via our Django backend.

According to [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381971/how-to-use-postgresqls-stored-procedures-or-functions-in-django-project)
in order to call a procedure from Django we have to type it in a file named: test.py,
placed in our migrations folder, like so:

```
from django.db import migrations

SQL = """
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_input_file()
AS $$
 CREATE TABLE TEMP(RowData VARCHAR(4000));

$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
"""

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('api', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [migrations.RunSQL(SQL)]
```

NOTES:
`python test.py` resulted in nothing.

`python manage.py migrate api` resulted in

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: api
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Then according to [this guide](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/call-stored-procedures/)
we have added in our backend views.py the following code:

```
            # apply stored procedure
            import psycopg2
            import os
            conn = psycopg2.connect(
                host=os.getenv('TDB_HOST'),
                database=os.getenv('TDB_NAME'),
                user=os.getenv('TDB_USER'),
                password=os.getenv('TDB_PASSWORD')
            )
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("CALL get_input_file();")
            conn.commit()
```

We have expected this test to successfully call the procedure.
We get:

```
procedure get_input_file() does not exist
LINE 1: CALL get_input_file();
             ^
HINT:  No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome the problem by following the next steps:

1. Create the procedure in the database itself (via GUI PgAdmin)
2. Call the procedure with `psycopg2`:

   ```
   call_script ='''CALL procedure();'''
   cur.execute(call_script)
   ```

No need for migrations.
No need for `test.py` file.